# Decision problems with verifiable proofs but not in polynomial time

Tags: complexity-theory, np

NP is a class of decision problems for which one can present a "certificate" that can be verified in polynomial time.

Are there any decision problems that have such "certificates" that can be verified faster than solving the problem(*), but verifying still takes superpolynomial time(*)?

(*) using the best-known method

Comment: SUCCINCT 3-SAT and other succinctly represented problems are good candidates. See for example https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18.../MIT18_405JS16_SuinctlyEcod.pdf.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus this link seems to be broken.

Comment: The correct link is https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-405j-advanced-complexity-theory-spring-2016/projects/MIT18_405JS16_SuinctlyEcod.pdf.